# Python dict() and the variable as an argument

Tags: python, dictionary, append

please take a look

```
>>> var = "name"
>>> dict(var=12)
{'var': 12}
```

but I need {'name': 12}

How to do this ?

I use dict() not dict[element] because in such a way that append element to my dict(graph is also Dictionary):

```
graph[v1] = dict(graph[v1], v2=weight)
```

Please help, how to do it or modify my append method

Comment: Please show us examples of your `graph`.

Comment: @ulidtko: `graph` seems to be a dictionary of dictionaries, and KuB intends to add a new item to one of the inner dictionaries.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Moment of insanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

```
graph[v1][v2] = weight
```

No need to recreate the whole dictionary just to add a new item.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> var = "name"
>>> {var : 12}
{'name': 12}
```

Comment: (+1) I think this is by far the cleanest way to do it (provided I am understanding the question correctly...)

Comment: in this way, I can not expand the dictionary, if the graph is like this {'a': {'a1':123, 'a2':456}, 'b': {...},...}

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it the simple way:

```
var = 'name'
d = dict()
d[var] = 12
graph[v1] = d
```

Or:

```
var = 'name'
graph[v1] = {var:12}
```

Or you could use the dict(items) trick:

```
var = 'name'
graph[v1] = dict([(var,12)]) # dict(d.items()) trick
```

Or you could be silly:

```
d = {var:12}
graph[v1] = dict(**d) # I *think* this works
```